# ASP.Net get an error when trying to adjust css in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in my code behind:

```
if (Request.QueryString["category"] == "9")
{
    HtmlControl downloadableProducts = (HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("downloadableProducts");
    downloadableProducts.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

It is generating the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on line 43 which is the this `downloadableProducts.Style.Add("display", "none");`

My div looks like this:

```
<div id="downloadableProducts" runat="server">
    <a href="#">Downloadedable Products</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I remove this line from my code behind:

```
HtmlControl downloadableProducts = (HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("downloadableProducts");
```

I get this error:

The name 'downloadableProducts' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Has downloadable products  been instantiated?

Comment: Well, the error is because it can't find that control (hence the NullReferenceException) because you are trying to perform a cast on a null object.  Can you post your relevant code showing you have initialized the object?

Comment: Can you debug? set a breakpoint at the line above (HtmlControl...), check if you get any result or a null

Comment: post your whole aspx page, because you can only find controls that are not inside any other container element (you would have to recursively find each container first)

Comment: I ran the debug, but the breakpoint able the HtmlControl and it says downloadableProducts null

Comment: you can directly do `downloadableProducts.Style.Add("display", "none")`

Comment: Is the code behind logic on the same page that has the control (e.g. Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs) ?  Your error is saying that the control can not be found.  Maybe your using a master page or user control ?

Answer (score 0):

Since downloadableProducts already runs at the server, you should be able to remove line 42. I commented it out below:

```
if (Request.QueryString["category"] == "9")
{
    //HtmlControl downloadableProducts  = HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("downloadableProducts");
    downloadableProducts.Style.Add("display", "none");
 }
```

This worked for me...

Comment: this gives me an error 'The name 'downloadableProducts' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Sounds like you could have a mismatch somewhere between your ASPX and CS file. Do these match in your ASPX `CodeFile**="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourPage"`

Comment: To clarify, those values in the ASPX should match the class name in the CS file `public partial class YourPage: System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Are you writing code in a static function/property?  If so, then of course instance members (like "downloadableProducts") won't be visible/accessible.  (I suspect you're not, since I doubt Request.QueryString would be accessible there either.  But just wanted to check...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DIV is defined directly in the ASPX file (`<div id="downloadableProducts" runat="server">`).  Thus, you shouldn't need to call `FindControl()` at all.  `this.downloadableProducts` should give you direct access to the control.

Note: this assumes the control is defined in the same class as the code-behind.  For example, your DIV is defined in `Foobar.aspx`, and you're writing code in `Foobar.aspx.cs`.  (Both of those files make up a single class: `Foobar`)

By contrast, if your DIV is defined in `Fred.ascx`, you will NOT be able to access it directly from the `Barney.ascx.cs` file.  (These two files are defining two different classes: `Fred` and `Barney`)